# how to adjust size of force directed graph in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have implemented a force directed graph which visualizes shared borders between countries.The layout of graph goes out of svg boundaries,is there way to resize the graph size,so that graph layout stays within graph boundaries.can size of simulation be pre set to adjust to the change in the width and height of window?

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/renx777/pen/BmBvzL)

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener("load", loaded);

function loaded() {
  const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

  var nodes = data.nodes;
  var links = data.links;

  // sets up svg
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = +svg.attr("width"),
      height = +svg.attr("height");

  // handle color of the nodes i gueess,gotta know what schemeCategory method does
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

  // starts simulation
  var simulation = d3

  .forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink())

  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width /2, height / 2))


  // creates lines in graph,
  var link = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
    return Math.sqrt(3);
  });

  //creates nodes..for this example,you need to set node to images
  var node = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll(".node")
  //pass node data
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
.append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href",function(d){return "https://cdn.rawgit.com/hjnilsson/country-flags/master/svg/"+d.code+".svg" })
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y", -8)
      .attr("width", 16)
      .attr("height", 16)



  .call(
    d3
    .drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended)
  );



  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.country; });

  simulation.nodes(nodes).on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link").links(links);

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });


  }

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
}
request.open(
  "GET",
  "https://www.cs.mun.ca/~h65ped/Public/country%20data%20for%20force%20directed%20graph/countries.json",
  true
);
request.send(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attractive forces of the built-in [d3.forceManyBody](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#many-body) can be modified with the strength() method so try something like

```
  // starts simulation
  var simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink())
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width /2, height / 2))
```

If that constrains the other items too closely then you would have to implement your own force method which can constrain items based on the SVG size. See [d3.force](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forces) for a description of what is happening under-the-hood and to see how you could produce your own function.